# Delete old Versions of same package

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py, python-packaging

I distribute my own package via distutils (command: python setup.py sdist) and install this package on my server (command: python setup.py install).

After updating my package several times with different version numbers I have different versions on my server. For example, there are package-1.1.0 and package-1.0.0 simultaneously installed and visible within the list of installed packages. Until now, this is not a problem as python chooses the most recent version out of all installed versions.

My question:
Is there a command to uninstall those old versions?

Thanks alot for the answers :)

Comment: which is your os?

Comment: Local: Windows 7; Server: Windows Server 2012 R2